# How to avoid infinite re-rendering with event listener in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, electron, addeventlistener

I have a React/ Electron app. I need to get some database table from my main.js, and I need to set the state to this table.

For this, i have written the following listener:

```
ipcRenderer.on('sendTable', (evt, arg) => {
  this.props.setTable(arg);
});
```

It waits for main.js to send a 'sendTable' event, with the table as the argument. Then, I set my Redux store to that table.
This kind of works.

However, I don't know where to put this listener. If I put it in the constructor or render function of my component, I end up with an infinite loop. But I need to set this up once, since I do need to listen. Where could I put it?

Comment: Never change the state in the render as it will cause an infinite loop. Try putting it in componentDidMount: function()

Comment: Thanks. I get the same infinite loop when I put it into the `componentDidMount` function though. :(

Comment: Sorry, there was a different mistake in there as well. It does work now. If you submit this as an answer, I would pick that. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to attach the event listeners in the `componentDidMount` and detach the event listeners in the `componentWillUnmount`!

See the code example:

```
class Foobar extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('sendTable', (evt, arg) => {
      this.props.setTable(arg);
     });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Make sure to remove the DOM listener when the component is unmounted
    // read the ipcMain documentation to understand how to attach and detach listeners
    ipcMain.removeListener(channel, listener)
  }

  render() {
   // stuff
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks. how would i *actually* remove the event listener though? is there a function i could use?

Comment: yup. there's a removeListener method (see https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md )

Comment: I'd love to see an updated version of this answer!